# Component Exist Message Box too Big - InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a component list of more than 80 options,where user can select and then install.
The setup remembers the previous install components and automatically checks the Components, Now if user deselects all, the "Component Exist" Warning Message Box is shown.
Because user deselected all 80 options the list becomes to long and the Message box goes out of screen space and user is now stuck.
I know there is NoUninstallWarning in Messages which has the text for the warning message and takes one argument as %1

Is there a way I can change the argument value , rather than having all options listed in indiviual line , I would like to have them as comma separated?

 Or if I can have a Scrollbar in the Message box?

Please help

Comment: With most applications it is generally a bad idea to have the user install some version of the application and then upgrade individual components but leave other components at the older versions, which is what would happen if users unticked components and ignored the warning.

Answer (score 1):

No, this message is internal and you can't customise it like that without modifying Inno's own source code.

In that situation the user shouldn't be completely stuck -- they should be able to press ESC to return to the component selection window and then select everything again.

A simple way to avoid this problem is to not allow the user to deselect components, once installed.  You can do this with a bit of code like this:

```
var
  InstalledComponentsDisabled: Boolean;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageId: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if (CurPageId = wpSelectComponents) and
     (WizardForm.PrevAppDir <> '') and
     not InstalledComponentsDisabled then begin
    InstalledComponentsDisabled := True;
    for i := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do begin
      if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[i] then begin
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[i] := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This has a similar effect to making anything already installed on upgrades `fixed`.

An alternate option is to put `disablenouninstallwarning` on all of your components and then either implement the messagebox completely yourself, add a bit of static text warning about removing components permanently on the page, or even do something to actually support removing components (eg. `[InstallDelete]` entries or UninsHs).

Comment: Hi Miral,
Thanks for sharing your thoughts.
I don't want to disable the selected Components, as there may be situation on upgrades that they only want certain components.

Is there a way to add scrollbar on the message box?

If not, When I add disablenouninstallwarning on all components and when user deselected all, there comes a empty message box, how can I hide that message box ? Is there any way to hide the message box?